# Why are my variables not equal?

Tags: javascript, string, equals, scriptlet

So I have 2 variables. One is written in javascript, the other in a scriplet in jsp. They both are strings and they both have a value of "4" when I print them. When I do .getClass() they're both of the string class but when I print out asking if they are .equals() OR even if I do (which I know is incorrect for strings) == it prints out false.

These are my variables and how they are declared.

```
String showingValue = "<script>document.writeln(selectedCopyValue)</script>";

String val4 = "4";
```

The selectedCopyValue is a varible that is written in javascript above. It is declared (for now as it is hardcoded for testing) as:

```
String selectedCopyValue = "4";
```

So why when I do something even as extensive as:

```
out.print(val4.trim().toString().equals(showingValue.trim().toString()));
```

Does it print out false?

Comment: Java doesn't process javascript

Comment: Because `showingValue` is `"<script>document.writeln(selectedCopyValue)</script>"`, not `"4"`. The script is not interpreted.

Comment: Learn about the page life cycle!

Comment: You are comparing the string "4" to "<script>document.writeln(selectedCopyValue)</script>"

Comment: Why in the universe would you expect the string `"<script>document.writeln(selectedCopyValue)</script>"` to be equal to the string `"4"`? They're not remotely equal. They don't share a single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print `showingValue`, the browser executes the script and displays 4. When you compare the strings, it doesn't execute the script, so it literally compares the strings:

`"4"` is not equal to `"<script>document.writeln(selectedCopyValue)</script>"`

Comment: +1 for your kindness and forbearance/patience. I consider myself patient, but after reading the question, I just facepalm'ed and lost heart to responding today..